# What is this plastic clip on that came on the leg of my tripod?

Tags: tripod

I recently acquired a Manfrotto tripod and it came with this plastic clip on one of the legs, what is its purpose?

[image]

Comment: If it isn't on the legs, it is already "lost" when you need it. If you ever really do lose it, any nutdriver of the correct size will work. It just won't clip onto the leg...

Comment: I've been wondering exactly this. Great question.

Comment: @Brian I don't go anywhere with my tripod without my camera bag, which is where it now resides.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a tool to adjust the tension on the locks for each leg section. The six-sided socket fits over the head of the nut to the upper left in the picture below. If the leg still moves under load when 'locked', then release the leg lock and tighten the nut with the tool. Don't tighten it too much though, or you won't be able to push the lock tab back down.

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks, I don't think I will be keeping it clipped to the leg it seems very easy to lose.

Comment: Some folks tie a lanyard string through the little hole in the tool and then use tape to secure the lanyard to one of the legs.   http://philipschwarzphotography.files.wordpress.com/2012/12/manfrotto-bg055cxpro3-tripod-12-12-_0895.jpg